# Wrong encoding on switching from cake 2.6 to 2.9

Tags: mysql, cakephp, character-encoding

On 2.6 was alright, but when I switched to 2.9, and try to write something to the DB, I'm getting something like

[image: image description]

on the web it looks like usual,

[image]

- DB encoding is utf8_general_ci
- cakephp is on UTF-8 like always.

When I try to insert some string manually, I'm getting odd characters on my web site

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called "Mojibake".  See [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for further discussion, including the likely things that caused the problem.

(I do not have a Cake-specific fix.)